# Simple JavaScript string variable returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript

I'm basically trying to create a url friendly query string with user input. The variables replace spaces and @s and add it all together and then the function should display the url in the paragraph. This is making me feel really stupid because I know it's something really simple I'm messing up. Please point out my mistake. And as a side note, is there a better way to do all this replacing without all the variables?

The following code should return a string similar to:
**https://www.somewebsite.com/formhandler.php?&fname=gordie&address=123+main+street&email=something%40somewhere.com**

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">

var fnstr = document.getElementById("firstname").value; 
var fncutspace = fnstr.trim();
var fnrepspace = fncutspace.replace(/ /g,"+");
var fnfinal = fnrepspace.replace("@","%40");
var adstr = document.getElementById("address").value; 
var adcutspace = adstr.trim();
var adrepspace = adcutspace.replace(/ /g,"+");
var adfinal = adrepspace.replace("@","%40");
var emstr = emdocument.getElementById("firstname").value; 
var emcutspace = emstr.trim();
var emrepspace = emcutspace.replace(/ /g,"+");
var emfinal = emrepspace.replace("@","%40");
var domurl = "https://www.somewebsite.com/formhandler.php?&fname=";
var secondchunk = "&address=";
var thirdchunk = "&email=";
var url = domurl + fnfinal + secondchunk + adfinal + thirdchunk + emfinal;

function createurl() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = url;
}
</SCRIPT>

<FORM action="javascript:createurl()">
Fisrt Name:<INPUT id="firstname" TYPE="TEXT"><br>
street address:<INPUT id="address" TYPE="TEXT"><br>
email address:<INPUT id="email" TYPE="TEXT"><br>
<input type="submit" value="GO">
</FORM>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's supposed to be based on the user input, you should move the variables to be declared and set inside `createurl`:

```
function createurl() {
    var fnstr = document.getElementById("firstname").value; 
    var fncutspace = fnstr.trim();
    var fnrepspace = fncutspace.replace(/ /g,"+");
    var fnfinal = fnrepspace.replace("@","%40");
    // etc.
    var url = domurl + fnfinal + secondchunk + adfinal + thirdchunk + emfinal;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = url;
}
```

That way they'll be set to the current input values at the time the function is called.

> And as a side note, is there a better way to do all this replacing without all the variables?

You can chain the method calls:

```
var fnInput = document.getElementById('firstname');
var fnfinal = fnInput.value.trim().replace(/ /g,"+").replace("@","%40");
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a big tip in the right direction! but when I put the variables inside the function I no longer get even an "undefined". nothing happens at all. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @Gordie Are you using a [JavaScript debugger](http://www.browserstack.com/debugging-tools)? If not, you really should find one for your browser. [Giving it a try](http://jsfiddle.net/aHA2e/), I get the error "*emdocument is not defined*." I believe that was meant to be `document` rather than `emdocument`?

Comment: I'm so embarrassed thank you and I will definitely be finding one. I wrote the bulk of this in notepad at work where they don't allow browser add ons. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<FORM action="javascript:createurl()">
Fisrt Name:<INPUT id="firstname" TYPE="TEXT"><br>
street address:<INPUT id="address" TYPE="TEXT"><br>
email address:<INPUT id="email" TYPE="TEXT"><br>
<input type="submit" value="GO">
</FORM>

<p id="demo"></p>

<SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">

var fnstr = document.getElementById("firstname").value; 
var fncutspace = fnstr.trim();
var fnrepspace = fncutspace.replace(/ /g,"+");
var fnfinal = fnrepspace.replace("@","%40");
var adstr = document.getElementById("address").value; 
var adcutspace = adstr.trim();
var adrepspace = adcutspace.replace(/ /g,"+");
var adfinal = adrepspace.replace("@","%40");
var emstr = emdocument.getElementById("firstname").value; 
var emcutspace = emstr.trim();
var emrepspace = emcutspace.replace(/ /g,"+");
var emfinal = emrepspace.replace("@","%40");
var domurl = "https://www.somewebsite.com/formhandler.php?&fname=";
var secondchunk = "&address=";
var thirdchunk = "&email=";
var url = domurl + fnfinal + secondchunk + adfinal + thirdchunk + emfinal;

function createurl() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = url;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

You should probably execute all javascript functions that depend on DOM in the `window.onload` callback function.

```
window.onload = function ()
{
Javascript code goes here
}
```

Comment: I put the script underneath as you suggested but now i just get "undefinedundefinedundefine..." instaead of just "undefined". I'm a little fuzzy on how to use window.onload. would you mind updating your answer and showing me the proper way to do this? I would greatly appreciate it, thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You may just want to use the built in JavaScript functions `encodeURI`, `encodeURIComponent`, or `escape` as appropriate: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

Answer (score -1):

You should use `encodeURIComponent(string)` instead of trimming/replacing you're doing right now.